# How to control react native animation from another component?

Tags: react-native, react-animated

I have an architure like this.
The goal is to animate `Child2` in and out of screen via `Child1`.

```js
const [value] = useState(new Animate.Value(0))
<Parent>
  <Child1 value={value}>
  <Child2 value={value}>
</Parent>
```

**Child1**

```js
Animated.timing(props.value, {toValue: 100, duration:300})
```

**Child2**

```js
<Animated.View style={{bottom:props.value}}>...</Animate.View>
```

1. For animation to happen, we can't update state cause that'll cause a re-render right?
2. Have tried to animate `value` in Child1 but nothing happens. Is the architure possible? How do I control Child2 from Child1?

Answer (score 2):

Some mistakes I did.
1. Called `Aminate.timing` without `.start()`.
2. Tried to pass `Animate.Value` to styled-components which doesn't seem to be supported.

After using `Animate.View` with inline style, I was actually able to call in Child1 to trigger the animation in Child2 with

```js
Animated.timing(props.value, {toValue: 100, duration:300}).start()
```

Comment: Fair enough, then mark this question as "answered".

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a callback as a property to your children and call it from there. Something like this:

```
...

someCallback () {
    this.setState({//SET SOMETHING})
}

<Parent>
  <Child1 value={value} animationCallback={this.someCallback}>
...
</Parent>
```

And inside your child you call it with `this.props.animationCallback()`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to use `Animated` instead of `Animate`, i.e. `Animated.View` and `Animated.timing`

You should put your `Animated.timing` function in the parent component. Pass the function down (as a prop) to the child that you want to trigger it. Then pass the Animated value down to the child that displays the animation itself.

This way you can have the animation triggered by something in `Child2` but the animation itself occurs in `Child1`.

Comment: thanks for spotting that. i used `Animated` actually. will fix the question. and good point on passing function props too.